# Shapeless HList type checking

Tags: scala, shapeless, type-level-computation

I am using Shapeless and have the following method to compute the difference between two HLists:

```
  def diff[H <: HList](lst1: H, lst2:H):List[String] = (lst1, lst2) match {
    case (HNil, HNil)                 => List()
    case (h1::t1, h2::t2) if h1 != h2 => s"$h1 -> $h2" :: diff(t1, t2)
    case (h1::t1, h2::t2)             => diff(t1, t2)
    case _                            => throw new RuntimeException("something went very wrong")
  }
```

Since both parameters to the method take an `H`, I would expect HLists of different types to not compile here. For example:

```
diff("a" :: HNil, 1 :: 2 :: HNil)
```

Shouldn't compile but it does, and it produces a runtime error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: something went very wrong`. Is there something I can do to the type parameters to make this method only accept two sides with identical types?

Comment: You don't seem to be handling the case where only one of `lst1` or `lst2` is empty, which might very well explain your error.

Comment: I understand the error, but I want a compile error, not a runtime one

Comment: Oh, I see what you are trying to achieve. Unfortunately, the base `HList` trait is unparameterized, and so in your method call `H` is just resolved to `Hlist` (which is indeed a supertype of any `Hlist` irrespective of the concrete element types). See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the base `HList` trait is unparameterized, and so in your method call `H` is just resolved to `Hlist` (which is indeed a supertype of any `Hlist` irrespective of the concrete element types).
To fix this we have to change the definition somewhat, and rely instead on generalized type constraints:

```
def diff[H1 <: HList, H2 <: HList](lst1: H1, lst2: H2)(implicit e: H1 =:= H2): List[String] = (lst1, lst2) match {
  case (HNil, HNil)                 => List()
  case (h1::t1, h2::t2) if h1 != h2 => s"$h1 -> $h2" :: diff(t1, t2)
  case (h1::t1, h2::t2)             => diff(t1, t2)
  case _                            => throw new RuntimeException("something went very wrong")
}
```

Let's check:

```
scala> diff("a" :: HNil, 1 :: 2 :: HNil)
<console>:12: error: Cannot prove that shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil] =:= shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[Int,shapele
              diff("a" :: HNil, 1 :: 2 :: HNil)
                  ^

scala> diff("a" :: HNil, "b" :: HNil)
res5: List[String] = List(a -> b)

scala> diff("a" :: 1 :: HNil, "b" :: 2 :: HNil)
res6: List[String] = List(a -> b, 1 -> 2)
```

Now we could still "cheat" and explicitly set H1 and H2 to `HList`, and we're back to square one.

```
scala> diff[HList, HList]("a" :: HNil, 1 :: 2 :: HNil)
java.lang.RuntimeException: something went very wrong
  at .diff(<console>:15)
  at .diff(<console>:13)
```

Unfortunately I don't think this is easily solvable (it certainly is though, but I don't have a quick solution).

Comment: There is [a slightly simpler solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31192042/334519).

Answer (score 10):

One thing the other answers don't really address is the fact that this is entirely a type inference problem, and can be solved by simply breaking the parameter list in two:

```
def diff[H <: HList](lst1: H)(lst2: H): List[String] = (lst1, lst2) match {
  case (HNil, HNil)                 => List()
  case (h1::t1, h2::t2) if h1 != h2 => s"$h1 -> $h2" :: diff(t1)(t2)
  case (h1::t1, h2::t2)             => diff(t1)(t2)
  case _                            => throw new RuntimeException("bad!")
}
```

Which gives us what we want:

```
scala> diff("a" :: HNil)(1 :: 2 :: HNil)
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.HNil]]
 required: shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]
       diff("a" :: HNil)(1 :: 2 :: HNil)
                           ^
```

This works (i.e. doesn't compile inappropriately and then blow up at runtime) because Scala's type inference for methods works on a per-parameter list basis. If `lst1` and `lst2` are in the same parameter list, `H` will be inferred to be their least upper bound, which generally isn't what you want.

If you put `lst1` and `lst2` in separate parameter lists, then the compiler will decide what `H` is as soon as it sees `lst1`. If `lst2` doesn't have the same type, it blows up (which is what we're aiming for).

You can still break this by explicitly setting `H` to `HList`, but that's on your own head, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes this is a type inference problem. And yes introducing a second parameter list is a way to overcome this. This is actually exactly what my solution takes advantage of (in this case the second parameter list contains the implicit evidence, instead of `lst2`). Your solution is slightly simpler, and mine is slightly more natural to use (I guess).

Answer (score 1):

I could provide little bit more strict variant, that could not be tricked with explicit type parameters.

```
object diff {
    class Differ[T <: HList](val diff: (T, T) => List[String])

    def apply[T <: HList](l1: T, l2: T)(implicit differ: Differ[T]): List[String] = differ.diff(l1, l2)

    implicit object NilDiff extends Differ[HNil]((_, _) => Nil)

    implicit def ConsDiff[H, T <: HList : Differ] = new Differ[H :: T]({
      case (h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2) if h1 != h2 => s"$h1 -> $h2" :: diff(t1, t2)
      case (h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2) => diff(t1, t2)
    })
  }
```

It's definitely much more complex than above one, and i've tried to use [Polymorphic function](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values) but could not end with proper recursion compiled.